# jmeter-maven-plugin libraries management

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have such plugin configuration in my `pom.xml`

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jmeter.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <jmeterExtensions>
                    <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-json:2.4</artifact>
                    <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.1</artifact>
                </jmeterExtensions>
                <junitLibraries>
                    <artifact>com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0</artifact>
                </junitLibraries>
                <testFilesIncluded>
                    <jMeterTestFile>${tests.include}</jMeterTestFile>
                </testFilesIncluded>
                <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                    <xms>2048</xms>
                    <xmx>2048</xmx>
                </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                <customPropertiesFiles>
                    <!-- Custom property file -->
                </customPropertiesFiles>
                <propertiesJMeter>
                   <!-- Some properties that I pass into jmeter -->
                </propertiesJMeter>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

After I run `mvn clean verify` I get such libsat `/target/jmeter/lib/`:

`json-path-2.1.0.jar
json-path-2.2.0.jar`

and in log file I see that jmeter fails from time to time with such exception:

`jmeter.extractor.json.jsonpath.JSONPostProcessor: Error processing JSON content in Select Team Name, message:Could not compile inline filter : [?(@.id=="29011")]`

Note that this `[?(@.id=="29011")]` is only a part of expression. Full expression is looks like similar to this: `$.teamData[?(@.id=="29011")].name`

I expect that this error somehow related to this multiple libs

Comment: Can't you switch to use later JMeter with latest plug-in? Because JMeter 3 comes with built-in JSON extractor (which uses json-path-2.2.0), and jmeter-maven-plugin version > 2.0 supports JMeter 3, so you don't need plug-in and you won't have version conflict I think.

Comment: Hi UBIK, I think, Maybe he doesn't have the time/care to write a detailed answer that meets the quality standard or maybe he leaves a comment to point the right direction for the questioner. And yes, I don't see anything wrong with this. Thanks.

Comment: @KirilS., I tried to remove all `jmeterExtensions` and as a result I got exception about missed `JSONPathExtractor` which comes with `jmeter-plugins-json`. I can not say exactly where it is used. But in my tests I have a lot of jsonPath post processors.

Comment: Which version of JMeter do you have?

Comment: @KirilS., I use ` <jmeter.maven.plugin.version>2.0.3</jmeter.maven.plugin.version>` version of maven plugin and this plugin uses JMeter3

Comment: Yes, that version will use JMeter 3.0 by default, which means you don't need add-on for JSON post-processor. I'm not sure if you need to convert it or it will be converted automatically. Try via UI maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Use last version of the plugin which has solved this issue as described in release notes:

> https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md